# Dynamic Text import

Tags: excel, vba

If anyone can help me with the below.  Basically I want the file to change according to the date the file bath always remains the same but the file will change i.e. 02102020 then 03102020 and so on.

I recorded a macro which works perfectly.  However when I try to amend the import path to a reference it stops working,  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro


    Sheets("Sheet7").Select
    FileLoc = Range("Z16")
    BOBF = Range("Z10")
    
    Sheets("BOB Current").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;(FileLoc)" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `"TEXT;(FileLoc)"` to `"TEXT;" & FileLoc`?

Comment: Thank you when I try this it get an error on the below line                                   .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Comment: In fact, `.Refresh` starts the "real" action. All previous commands are just presetting the params for the real operation (just like when you import a text file to Excel and click through a number of tabs of the wizzard). So a semantic error will be revealed at `.Refresh`. I'd proceed with the "halving" method (=comment out any half of the params to leave defaults everywhere and see if it works or not). BTW most probably the file is wrong somehow. You can check it with `Dir(FileLoc)` beforehand.

Comment: Make sure, too, that Z16 has the full path specification for the file, e.g., C:\Folder1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\...\FileName.FileExtension.

Comment: I'm curious, too, what you use BOBF for? You can greatly simplify your code by not "selecting". Your eyes have to see things (and the recorder captured your doing so), but your code doesn't. Instead of "selecting" Sheet7 , then  "selecting" the sheet "Bob Current" and cell A1, you can say `Fileloc=Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("Z16").Value2` and change your WITH statement to: `With Worksheets("Bob Current").Range("A1").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _`